# How to prove that $f(x,y ) = - x^{\alpha}y ^{1-\alpha}$ is convex when $0 < \alpha < 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I want to prove that $f(x,y ) = - x^{\alpha}y ^{1-\alpha}$ is convex when $0 < \alpha < 1$ on $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2: x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$. However, the exponent $0< \alpha < 1$ is causing me a lot of trouble. I don't get anything with $f(tu + (1-t)v) \leq t f(u) + (1-t)t(v)$. Any other method involving $\nabla f$ or $\nabla^2 f$ doesn't seem useful either because of the discontinuities of the derivatives of $f$ at $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: How do you define the function on all of the place?

Comment: @copper.hat: $f(x, y) = - x^\alpha y^{1-\alpha}, \forall (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$ and $0<\alpha < 1$

Comment: So, if we have $\alpha=1/2$, then what is the value of $f $ at $(-1,-1)$?

Comment: @richrow: Thanks. I already corrected it.

Comment: You can show that the Hessian is positive semi definite on $x>0,y>0$ and hence is convex there, Since $f$ is continuous, it is straightforward to show using the definition that $f$ is convex everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) page on convex functions:

> A twice differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) on the interior of the convex set.

Using Mathematica I found the Hessian for your function to be:
$$
\mathbf H=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 (\alpha -1) \alpha  \left(-x^{\alpha -2}\right) y^{1-\alpha } & (\alpha -1) \alpha 
   x^{\alpha -1} y^{-\alpha } \\
 (\alpha -1) \alpha  x^{\alpha -1} y^{-\alpha } & (\alpha -1) \alpha  \left(-x^{\alpha
   }\right) y^{-\alpha -1} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily differentiable on the axes (take $\alpha={1 \over 2}$ for example), so some finessing is required to use this result.